# Windows, Ubuntu and Grub with multiple disks

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a laptop with one built-in SSD of 128GB. I use an ultrabay SSD of 256GB instead of my CD/DVD player that I use from time to time.

My plan is to have Windows as primary OS on the built-in SSD, and an Ubuntu partition on the ultrabay SSD. I would like to be able to boot Windows without necessarily having the ultrabay SSD plugged-in.

After installing Windows on the built-in SSD and Ubuntu on the external, all the grub files are located on the external. Hence I cannot boot Windows without the external ssd plugged-in in the ultrabay.

Is there a way to have Grub "installed" on the built-in ssd independently of ubuntu?

Thank you in advance for your inputs!

Comment: do you have a key to press on this box wile booting it up to chose what device/drive to boot (@hear it is F12) if so it may be easier to fix windows boot loader without the ultrabay  in and then install Ubuntu to the ultrabay and install grub to the ultrabay ,,,,,,,,,then when you start the box it will boot to windows by default or hit the device to boot key and chose the ultrabay to boot ubuntu ,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can boot windows without external SSD, for this purpose you will have to install Grub Loader into your primary SSD.

The easiest approach is to install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) in Ubuntu and Run it from terminal by executing following command in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then choose advanced options and install grub into internal SSD , it will be named something as `/dev/sda`

Comment: In this scenario where will the grub.cfg  and the rest of what is usually in /boot/grub go?

Comment: It will go into the SSD where you will install grub. i.e. internal SSD.

Comment: @Faizan so it will create a new partition on the same drive as the windows installation and will hold the /boot/grub?

Comment: Grub generally doesn't require creating new partition for its install like windows but you can create a separate boot partition in grub. In your case I suppose it will create a separate partition for boot since there is no `ext4` partition on internal SSD.